# Ansible extracting atributes and create new dictionary

Tags: templates, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a json object which looks as follows:

```
  [
     {
        "id": "subnet-1",
        "tags": {
            "Name": "showcase"
        }
     },
    {
        "id": "subnet-2",
        "tags": {
            "Name": "qa"
        }
    }
   ]
```

and i would like to create a new dictionary with only subnetIds with tag name 'Name' used as key and 'id' used as value as follows:

```
   {
    "showcase": "subnet-1",
    "qa": "subnet-2",
   }
```

currently i have following code which does not help:

```
 - name: Populate SubnetIds
      set_fact:
        SubnetIds: "{{ subnet_facts.subnets | map(attribute='tags.Name') | join(',') }}"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to reshuffle complex data structure is a `template` lookup.
Knowing the fact, that Ansible evaluates JSON data after templating, we can do the following.

Create a helper **subnets.j2** that forms a desired object:

```
{
 {% for s in subnets %}
 "{{ s.tags.Name }}":"{{ s.id }}" {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
}
```

Call it via lookup in your playbook:

```
- name: Populate SubnetIds
  set_fact:
    SubnetIds: "{{ lookup('template', 'subnets.j2') }}"
  vars:
    subnets: "{{ subnet_facts.subnets }}"
```

As the last step of templating procedure Ansible tries to evaluate JSON into object, so `SubnetIds` in this example becomes an ordinary dictionary.

If you craft helper template for specific task, you can use `subnet_facts.subnets` instead of `subnets` inside j2-file, so there is no need to pass additional `vars` with `subnets` value.