# Add dictionary to Ansible variable recursively

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

I have a variable in Ansible playbook that I need to fill information from hosts. If I fill it in a static way:

```
mongodb_replication_params:
  - { host_name: "{{ hostvars[groups['mongo'][0]]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}", host_port: "{{ mongodb_net_port }}", host_type: replica }
  - { host_name: "{{ hostvars[groups['mongo'][1]]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}", host_port: "{{ mongodb_net_port }}", host_type: replica }
  - { host_name: "{{ hostvars[groups['mongo'][2]]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}", host_port: "{{ mongodb_net_port }}", host_type: replica }
```

It would store in correct json format:

```
[
    {
        "host_name": "172.31.xx.xxx", 
        "host_port": 27017, 
        "host_type": "replica"
    }, 
    {
        "host_name": "172.31.xx.xxx", 
        "host_port": 27017, 
        "host_type": "replica"
    }, 
    {
        "host_name": "172.31.xx.xxx", 
        "host_port": 27017, 
        "host_type": "replica"
    }
]
```

However, I'd need to do it recursively. I tried [Jinja2](https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2016/01/26/howto-introduction-to-ansible-variables/) loop:

```
mongodb_replication_params: |
  {% for host in groups['mongo'] %}
    - { hostname: "{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}", host_port: "{{ mongodb_net_port }}", host_type: replica }
  {% endfor %}
```

It stored in string instead of json:

```
- { hostname: \"172.31.xx.xxx\", host_port: \"27017\", host_type: replica }\n  - { hostname: \"172.31.xx.xxx\", host_port: \"27017\", host_type: replica }\n  - { hostname: \"172.31.xx.xxx\", host_port: \"27017\", host_type: replica }\n
```

I don't know what modification needed for the Jinja2 statement. Or maybe there are Ansible modules that could be used. Please help, any suggestions welcome!

*Edit*: In regard to how the variable **mongodb_replication_params** is used, please reference to the **usage** section of this [MongoDB Ansible playbook](https://github.com/UnderGreen/ansible-role-mongodb#usage)

Comment: What do you mean by recursive?

Comment: Say, in a loop, as in my Jinja2 example

Comment: There is lack of context – where do you define this vars? Why you define them as YAML and then say that it's JSON? If you need to construct complex variable in runtime, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40036807/2795592) to other question.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Edited to include reference to MongoDB ansible playbook. **mongodb_replication_params** is a variable that is defined in the playbook. Your answer to other question seem viable, I'll study it.