# Manipulate object in Ansible

Tags: ansible

EDIT 10OCT2017 thanks to @techraf to use jinja2 templating
I have an ansible tasks which is making me crazy (BTW I only have 1 day Ansible experience so I could be wrong in my tests/way of thinking). I m trying to convert an object into a different object. My original object is like this:

```
[
{"allowed":[{"IPProtocol":"tcp","ports":["1234-1235"]},{"IPProtocol":"udp","ports":["1238-1239"]}],
"description":"hello1",
"name":"hello1",
"sourceRanges":["128.0.0.0/16","192.0.0.0/16"]},
{"allowed":[{"IPProtocol":"tcp","ports":["2345-2346"]},{"IPProtocol":"udp","ports":["4567-4578"]}],
"description":"hello2",
"name":"hello2",
"sourceRanges":["128.0.0.0/16","192.0.0.0/16"]}
]
```

and I would like to transform it into:

```
[
{"allowed":"tcp:1234-1235,udp:1238-1239",
"description":"hello1",
"name":"hello1",
"sourceRanges":"128.0.0.0/16,192.0.0.0/16"},
{"allowed":"tcp:2345-2346,udp:4567-4578",
"description":"hello2",
"name":"hello2",
"sourceRanges":"128.0.0.0/16,192.0.0.0/16"}
]
```

I m flattening the protocols/ports and sourcerange.

I tried using jinja2 templates with the following ansible playbook:

```
#ansible-playbook issue.yml -i 'local,' --connection=local
- hosts:
  - local   tasks:
  - name: setVar
    set_fact:
        aOriginal='[{"allowed":[{"IPProtocol":"tcp","ports":["1234-1235"]},{"IPProtocol":"udp","ports":["1238-1239"]}],"description":"hello1","name":"hello1","sourceRanges":["128.0.0.0/16","192.0.0.0/16"]},{"allowed":[{"IPProtocol":"tcp","ports":["2345-2346"]},{"IPProtocol":"udp","ports":["4567-4578"]}],"description":"hello2","name":"hello2","sourceRanges":["128.0.0.0/16","192.0.0.0/16"]}]'
  - debug:
      var: aOriginal
  - name: Populate SubnetIds
    set_fact:
      test3: "{{ lookup('template', 'subnet2.j2') }}"
    vars:
      rules: "{{ aOriginal }}"
  - debug:
      var: test3
  - name: Create rules
    shell: gclofud compute firewall-rules create {{ item.name }} --allow {{ item.altIpProtos }} --description {{ item.description }} --source-ranges {{ item.flatSrcRanges }}
    with_items: "{{ test1 }}"
```

with my template file (same folder - with filename "subnet2.j2"):

```
[ { {% for s in rules %}name:{{s.name}},description:{{s.description}},allowed:{% for aOneAllowedProtoPort in s.allowed %}{{aOneAllowedProtoPort.IPProtocol}}:{% for aOneAllowedPort in aOneAllowedProtoPort.ports %}{{aOneAllowedPort}}{% endfor %}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %},sourceRanges:"{% for aOneAllowedSource in s.sourceRanges %}{{aOneAllowedSource}}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}{% endfor %} } ]
```

As you can see with the test3 result below:

```
ok: [local] => {
    "test3": "[\"name\":hello1,description:hello1,allowed:tcp:1234-1235,udp:1238-1239,sourceRanges:128.0.0.0/16,192.0.0.0/16\"name\":hello2,description:hello2,allowed:tcp:2345-2346,udp:4567-4578,sourceRanges:128.0.0.0/16,192.0.0.0/16]\n"
}
```

I manage to group together the protocole/ports and list of ranges Nevertheless it seems the output of templating is interpreted as a string and note as an object. I tried several tests (putting " around string do not help since ansible prefix them with ) and I m not sure what is happening.

I wonder if there something specific to do to have the result of template converted in an object. Still working on it and will update the question with my progress. Thx @techraf

FINAL UPDATE. I made it. Here is the ansible playbook (jinja2 template inside):

```
#ansible-playbook issue.yml -i 'local,' --connection=local
- hosts:
  - local
  tasks:
  - name: setVar
    set_fact:
        aOriginal='[{"allowed":[{"IPProtocol":"tcp","ports":["1234-1235"]},{"IPProtocol":"udp","ports":["1238-1239"]}],"description":"hello1","name":"hello1","sourceRanges":["128.0.0.0/16","192.0.0.0/16"]},{"allowed":[{"IPProtocol":"tcp","ports":["2345-2346"]},{"IPProtocol":"udp","ports":["4567-4578"]}],"description":"hello2","name":"hello2","sourceRanges":["128.0.0.0/16","192.0.0.0/16"]}]'
  - debug:
      var: aOriginal
  - name: Populate SubnetIds
    set_fact:
      test3='[ {% for s in rules %} {"name":"{{s.name}}","description":"{{s.description}}","allowed":"{% for aOneAllowedProtoPort in s.allowed %}{{aOneAllowedProtoPort.IPProtocol}}:{% for aOneAllowedPort in aOneAllowedProtoPort.ports %}{{aOneAllowedPort}}{% endfor %}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}","sourceRanges":"{% for aOneAllowedSource in s.sourceRanges %}{{aOneAllowedSource}}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}"}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %} {% endfor %} ]'
    vars:
      rules: "{{ aOriginal }}"
  - debug:
      var: test3
  - name: Create rules
    shell: gclofud compute firewall-rules create {{ item.name }} --allow {{ item.altIpProtos }} --description {{ item.description }} --source-ranges {{ item.flatSrcRanges }}
    with_items: "{{ test3 }}"
```

Comment: Looks like a requirement for a single Jinja2 template with three or four for-loops -- a task more laborious than challenging. It might take some time before someone writes this here for you. See this for an idea https://stackoverflow.com/q/40034175/2947502

Comment: Edit the question following your feedback with the progress made so far. THX for the hint about templating.

Comment: It's working. Thx @techraf for the hint about templating. I will post the final solution as an answer. Sadly I can not accept the comment of techraf even if it help me so much :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to the hint of @techraf about jinja2 template.

I m just sharing here the result in case it help someone in the future:

```
#ansible-playbook issue.yml -i 'local,' --connection=local
- hosts:
  - local
  tasks:
  - name: setVar
    set_fact:
        aOriginal='[{"allowed":[{"IPProtocol":"tcp","ports":["1234-1235"]},{"IPProtocol":"udp","ports":["1238-1239"]}],"description":"hello1","name":"hello1","sourceRanges":["128.0.0.0/16","192.0.0.0/16"]},{"allowed":[{"IPProtocol":"tcp","ports":["2345-2346"]},{"IPProtocol":"udp","ports":["4567-4578"]}],"description":"hello2","name":"hello2","sourceRanges":["128.0.0.0/16","192.0.0.0/16"]}]'
  - debug:
      var: aOriginal
  - name: Populate SubnetIds
    set_fact:
      test3='[ {% for s in rules %} {"name":"{{s.name}}","description":"{{s.description}}","allowed":"{% for aOneAllowedProtoPort in s.allowed %}{{aOneAllowedProtoPort.IPProtocol}}:{% for aOneAllowedPort in aOneAllowedProtoPort.ports %}{{aOneAllowedPort}}{% endfor %}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}","sourceRanges":"{% for aOneAllowedSource in s.sourceRanges %}{{aOneAllowedSource}}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}"}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %} {% endfor %} ]'
    vars:
      rules: "{{ aOriginal }}"
  - debug:
      var: test3
  - name: Create rules
    shell: gclofud compute firewall-rules create {{ item.name }} --allow {{ item.altIpProtos }} --description {{ item.description }} --source-ranges {{ item.flatSrcRanges }}
    with_items: "{{ test3 }}"
```